# convert-im6.q16: no images defined `test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258

Tags: ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I have an issue that I don't understand. I try to convert a PDF into a JPEG but I have the error :

`convert-im6.q16: no images defined 'scan0476.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258`

Here is the command line :

`convert -density 200 "/opt/maarch/dispatcher/tmp//DGS_scan0476.pdf[0]" -quality 100 -geometry x2000 -crop x500+0+1500 "scan0476.jpg"`

The `/opt/maarch/dispatcher/tmp/` folder have 777 rights and my pdf is good

The library is well installed with all the dependency needed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

This worked fine with my test:

```
#!/bin/sh
convert -density 200 "$1" -quality 100 -geometry x2000 -crop x500+0+1500 "$1.jpg"
```

results:

```
$ file my.pdf.jpg  JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 200x200, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1545x500, components 3
```